# Hackerrank `super-functional-strings` terminates due to timeout

Tags: string, python-3.x, python-2.7, substring

Given a string, `p`, consisting of lowercase letters, compute the summation of function
`F(p) = [len(p)**distinct(p)]%[10**9 + 7]`
over all possible distinct substrings of `F`. As the result is quite large, print it modulo 10**9 + 7.

For example for 'aba' it is:

- F(a) = 1
- F(ab) = 4
- F(aba) = 9
- F(b) = 1
- F(ba) = 4

For which the sum equals 19.

The following is my solution:

```
import os
import sys

def superFunctionalStrings(s):
    a=list()
    thesum=0
    length = len(s) + 1
    modu=10**9 + 7
    for j in range(length):
        for i in range(j+1, length):
            b = s[j:i]
            if b not in a:
                a.append(b)
                thesum += (len(b)**len(set(b)))%(modu)
    summ = thesum%(modu)       
    return(summ)
```

What can I do to optimize it so that timeout won't occur? (I'm guessing external libraries is not allowed)

Comment: Such tasks often assume that you can compute the remainder without computing the whole huge number, and can compute the number of distinct permutations without actually generating them. The timeout is likely an indication of that, too. It should not be taking as long as a brute-force approach would require. Google around for relevant math.

Comment: There's probably an approach using trees that would lend itself to answering this question...

Comment: I'd like to notice that `(x ** y) % (10**9 + 7)` is just `x ** y` for x < 10 and y < 9. Since y ≤ x, you can avoid the modulo op for all substrings that are shorter than 10. For x = 1 the value of the expression also equals 1, so you can just add `len(p)` to the sum and not loop through the substrings of length 1. Memoizing the results for substrings can also help for wtrings with a lot of repetition, like `abcacababc`.

Answer (score 1):

You say "distinct substrings", so for starters use a set instead of a list so that duplicate substrings don't get stored and so that you get O(1) lookup time. Also, you don't need the modulo until the end, and Python supports addition of arbitrarily large integers, so you don't necessarily need the modulo inside your loop. Finally, I'd try this using comprehensions so that Python can loop faster. Here's what those recommendations leave you with:

```
def superFunctionalStrings(s):
    a=list()
    thesum=0
    length = len(s) + 1
    modu=10**9 + 7
    substrs = {s[j:i] for j in range(length) for i in range(j+1, length)}
    return sum(len(b) ** len(set(b)) for b in substrs) % modu
```

I'm getting ~15-20x speedup by taking this approach.

Comment: although tips you mentioned were very useful , but the problem still persists.

Comment: As @9000 suggested, there's likely a solution that doesn't involve enumerating every possible substring like this. For example, the [Trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) data structure looks like an efficient way to convert your string into a tree of all possible substrings, at which point there might be an iterative solution for the computation you're looking for. This problem might be fun to work on, but don't expect someone else to solve the algorithmic challenge of this hackerrank problem for you, it's counter to the spirit of the site.

Answer (score 1):

One change that would remove an O(n) factor of complexity would be to make `a` a set instead of a list.

To compute `b in a` for a list requires searching through the whole list, O(n). Alternatively, computing `b in a` for a set is hashed which takes O(1).